# Tailwind Css rebuilt : how write a script "watch"?

Tags: json, tailwind-css, package.json, jit

I am newbie in js. I installed tailwind to update my website, to make it responsive.
It works fine after upgraded computer to win 10 (goodbye 7). But in VSCode, i have to run :

```
 "npx tailwindcss -i ./src/css/input.css -o ./src/css/output.css --watch"
```

each time i start a terminal to make tailwind starting to rebuilt.
I saw a package.js in a video that contains this line :

```
"scripts":{
       "watch": "postcss ./src/css/input.css -o ./src/css/output.css --watch"
          },
```

[image]

It would be more simple to code if this "watch" was working.

```
Exécution de la tâche : npm run watch 

npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! JSON.parse Invalid package.json: JSONParseError: Unexpected string in JSON at 
position 533 while parsing '{
npm ERR! JSON.parse   "name": "postcss-cli",
npm ERR! JSON.parse   "version": '
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse JSON data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse Note: package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
```

Anybody to make it clearer ?

I added the line in package.js, in
"node_modules\postcss-cli" :

[image]

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"  =>  thank you to remain anonymous  :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After have seen an other video at watch?v=2NT6VvfR9Hk at 4:33  i have added the line :

```
 "scripts": {
"watch": "tailwindcss -i ./src/css/input.css -o ./src/css/output.css --watch"
  },
```

in my package.js file not in postcss or postcss-cli directory, but in my tailwind-project directory.
Now when i start VSCode, no need to copy and paste the entire line "tailwindcss -i ./src/css/input.css -o ./src/css/output.css --watch" to start the automatic building :-)  : i just type :

```
npm run watch
```

And the building process starts.

Answer (score 2):

As the error message suggests, and probably your IDE suggests by the red squiggly underlines, the `package.json` is invalid JSON. You are missing a comma after the `test` script to delimit the entries in the `scripts` object and you have an erroneous trailing comma after the final `watch` entry in the `scripts` object. That section should look more like:

```json
  "pretest": "…",
  "test": "…",
  "watch": "postcss ./src/css/input.css -o ./src/css/output.css --watch"
}
```

Comment: Thank you to suggest. The photo up is on youtube at watch?v=JJn98rW_0TQ and at 5.00  :-)   i inserted my "watch" as it is shown.   The error message is on watch in photo 2, but not telling anything about a comma, but a string in line at 
position 533 , in an other file not mentioned.   This command watch would be so useful !

Comment: But it is ok for the comma after "test" :-) now i have a new error ; Unexpected token "}" (0x7D) in JSON at position 610.                                                                                             
  I also tried to remove the trailing comma after line "watch", but i get the same error at 610

Comment: There could be a syntax error around position 610.

Comment: Yes but in which file ?  also VSCode/Tailwind says    "npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-06-26T07_23_07_777Z-debug-0.log"    but these logs are not in the mentioned dirertory :-(

Comment: The file that is the cause of the error.